# Script cannot be executed from separate file but works fine from <script> tag

Tags: javascript, debugging, typeerror

The JavaScript below works perfect when running it from within a `<script> JS </script>` tag. However, as soon as I run the code from a separate file I get an Uncaught TypeError: cannot set property of innerHTML of null. I have no idea what is going on here. Any help is much appreciated.

```
// Admin Nightmode Switch
var nmStylesheet = document.getElementById("nightmodeon");

if (localStorage.getItem("lastActiveNmSheet")) {
   nmStylesheet.setAttribute('href', localStorage.getItem('lastActiveNmSheet'));
}

if (nmStylesheet.getAttribute('href') === "view/stylesheet/elmigo_nighton.css") {
  document.getElementById("nightmode").innerHTML = "<span><i class=\"fa fa-moon-o\"></i></span>";
}

function nightmode() {
  var nmButton = document.getElementById("nightmode");
  var nmIconDay = "<span><i class=\"fa fa-sun-o\"></i></span>";
  var nmIconNight = "<span><i class=\"fa fa-moon-o\"></i></span>";

  if (nmButton.innerHTML === nmIconDay) {
    nmButton.innerHTML = nmIconNight;
    nmStylesheet.setAttribute('href', 'view/stylesheet/elmigo_nighton.css');
    localStorage.setItem('lastActiveNmSheet', 'view/stylesheet/elmigo_nighton.css');
  } else {
    nmButton.innerHTML = nmIconDay;
    nmStylesheet.setAttribute('href', '#');
    localStorage.setItem('lastActiveNmSheet', '#');
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: Is your script located after the `nightmode` element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have done is reference the external JS script **before** the element it tries to interact with.

When you reference a .js script externally with a `<script>` tag you can envision that external script being written within wherever that `script` tag is.

JS runs sequentially, so if your external JS is reverenced prior to the elements you change being declared/ closed, it will not be able to identify them.

To resolve this, most developers put an js scripts just prior to the closing `</body>` tag

```html
<html>

<body>
<script>
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML="This element has been changed"
</script>
<div id="test"> This Id wont be chaged as it is looked for before it is declared! </div>
</body>



</html>
```

This is where the script, whether external via file or written in the code, is declared before the element it is trying to interact with

```html
<html>

<body>
<div id="test"> This Id wont be changed as it is looked for before it is declared! </div>
</body>

<script>
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML="This element has been changed"
</script>


</html>
```

This is where the script is declared after the element it is interacting with

Answer (score -4):

yow JS code runs before them html items are rendered, it is why all them nulls and stuff

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {

// Admin Nightmode Switch
var nmStylesheet = document.getElementById("nightmodeon");

if (localStorage.getItem("lastActiveNmSheet")) {
   nmStylesheet.setAttribute('href', localStorage.getItem('lastActiveNmSheet'));
}

if (nmStylesheet.getAttribute('href') === "view/stylesheet/elmigo_nighton.css") {
  document.getElementById("nightmode").innerHTML = "<span><i class=\"fa fa-moon-o\"></i></span>";
}

function nightmode() {
  var nmButton = document.getElementById("nightmode");
  var nmIconDay = "<span><i class=\"fa fa-sun-o\"></i></span>";
  var nmIconNight = "<span><i class=\"fa fa-moon-o\"></i></span>";

  if (nmButton.innerHTML === nmIconDay) {
    nmButton.innerHTML = nmIconNight;
    nmStylesheet.setAttribute('href', 'view/stylesheet/elmigo_nighton.css');
    localStorage.setItem('lastActiveNmSheet', 'view/stylesheet/elmigo_nighton.css');
  } else {
    nmButton.innerHTML = nmIconDay;
    nmStylesheet.setAttribute('href', '#');
    localStorage.setItem('lastActiveNmSheet', '#');
  }
}

});
```

Comment: This is simply not true. JavaScript in files _will_ be executed when it is loaded in. (Otherwise it wouldn't have thrown the error "_Uncaught TypeError: cannot set property of innerHTML of null_")

Comment: ohhh them the problem is this one. updated and like it

Comment: you need to use `DOMContentLoaded` event listener, the problem you have is due bcuz javascript run before the dom is rendered, so it is why you get them nulls and stuff

Comment: `DOMContentLoaded` is _a_ way to wait for the element to become available. Alternatively you can also place the script tag after the element is loaded in, or adding the `defer` attribute to the script tag. But this question is a [common duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element) and all of this is explained in that post. This question should've been closed as such, instead of answered.